# Jolly jumpers programming challenge

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, vectors, bitset

I have posted my solution to the jolly jumpers programming challenge(detailed [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=16&page=show_problem&problem=979)) for your review:

> A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute
>   values of the differences between successive elements take on all
>   possible values 1 through n - 1. For instance,
>
> `1 4 2 3`
>
> is a jolly jumper, because the absolute differences are 3, 2, and 1,
>   respectively. The definition implies that any sequence of a single
>   integer is a jolly jumper. Write a program to determine whether each
>   of a number of sequences is a jolly jumper.
>
> **Input**
>
> Each line of input contains an integer n < 3, 000 followed by n
>   integers representing the sequence.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each line of input generate a line of output saying `Jolly` or
>   `Not jolly`.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 4 1 4 2 3
> 5 1 4 2 -1 6
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
>  Jolly
>  Not jolly
> ```

```
//platform specific code
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif // WINDOWS

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin; 
using std::vector; 

const int MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 3000; 

int main()
{
    bool not_jolly; 
    vector<int> sequence(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, 0);
    vector<bool> in_sequence(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, false); 
    int sequence_length; 
    while (cin >> sequence_length) {
        not_jolly = false;
        std::fill(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0);
        std::fill(in_sequence.begin(), in_sequence.end(), false);
        for (int i = 0;i < sequence_length; i++) {
            cin >> sequence[i]; 
        }

        for (int i = 1;i < sequence_length; i++) {
            in_sequence[abs(sequence[i] - sequence[i - 1])] = true; 
        }

        for (int i = 1;i < sequence_length;i++) {
            if (!in_sequence[i]) {
                not_jolly = true; 
                break;
            }
        }

        if (not_jolly == false) {
            cout << "Jolly" << "\n"; 
        } else {
            cout << "Not jolly" << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to be broken. You allocate `in_sequence` to be the same size as the maximum sequence length, but use (the absolute value of) a difference between inputs as an index into it. Consider an input of `2 0 5000`. This will attempt to write to `in_sequence[5000]`, which doesn't exist. The description says `n` will be less than 3000, but doesn't place that restriction on the range of the other inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program already looks correct and simple enough, yet there are some thing that can be improved.

First and most important, you should have a unit test for the important part of the program. To extract this part, create a function `bool is_jolly(const std::vector<int> &numbers)`. Then you can easily write a test that calls this function and checks whether the returned value is what you expect.

There is a bug. When the sequence of number contains two numbers whose difference is 2147483648, the `abs` function will return a negative value, making your program crash. The difference might also be any other number, so you need to check whether the array index is valid. For a start, you could replace `array[index]` with `array.at(index)`, which throws an exception instead of crashing.

When you loop over an array, the array index should be of type `std::size_t` instead of it. Enable the compiler warnings, and it will complain about a *comparison between signed and unsigned*.

Variable names should not contain the word `not`. Just try to evaluate `if (!not_jolly != false)` in your head, or the double negation `not_jolly == false`. It would be easier to read if it were just `if (is_jolly) { … }`.

Nitpick: after a semicolon, there should be a space (see the `for` loops).

To use the algorithm `std::fill`, you have to include its header. From the top of my head, it should be `<algorithm>`.

When writing a line to the output, you can merge the strings, e.g. `std::cout << "Jolly\n";` — the form you are currently using is perfectly fine, I'm just mentioning this as a shorter alternative.

What you did great:

- Indenting your source code consistenly, so that it is easily readable
- Importing only a few names from the `std` namespace
- Checking for errors when reading from `std::cin` (at least in one case)
- Writing short and easy to understand code